# XSAVE consistency problem preventing avx on KVM guests running Jammy HWE

Tags: kernel, 22.04, kvm-virtualization

Using 22.04 Jammy with HWE on an openstack KVM guest VM triggers the following /var/log/kern.log message:

```
 ------------[ cut here ]------------
 XSAVE consistency problem, dumping leaves
 WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at arch/x86/kernel/fpu/xstate.c:606 paranoid_xstate_size_valid+0x138/0x158
 Modules linked in:
 CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper Not tainted 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu
 RIP: 0010:paranoid_xstate_size_valid+0x138/0x158
 Code: 10 41 0f b6 f4 48 c7 c7 70 b5 44 a8 e8 24 11 31 fe 41 80 e4 01 75 15 48 c7 c7 f8 02 be a7 c6 05 a4 0c f4 ff 01 e8 93 45 9f fe <0f> 0b e8 78 f7 ff ff 44 39 eb 0f 94 c0 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f
 RSP: 0000:ffffffffa8403db8 EFLAGS: 00010046 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
 RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000a00 RCX: 0000000000000000
 RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
 RBP: ffffffffa8403de0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
 R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
 R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000007
 FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffffffa8811000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: ffff88800008b000 CR3: 00000002566d6000 CR4: 00000000000406a0
 Call Trace:
  <TASK>
  fpu__init_system_xstate+0x41f/0x607
  fpu__init_system+0x155/0x196
  early_identify_cpu.constprop.0+0xf8/0x130
  early_cpu_init+0x90/0xa3
  setup_arch+0x49/0x8ab
  start_kernel+0x6c/0x4e4
  x86_64_start_reservations+0x24/0x2c
  x86_64_start_kernel+0xee/0x103
  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xe5/0xeb
  </TASK>
 ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

As a result, the avx feature isn't enabled in the kernel, failing some programs that require it (e.g [mongodb requires avx instruction set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/#x86_64)). This does not reproduce when disabling HWE and downgrading to GA kernel (5.15.110-0515110-generic).

I'm suspecting a regression in 5.19 kernel that would be more strict with possibly QEMU emulated XASVE CPUID features. Full diagnostics performed so far at https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/paas-templates/issues/1960#issuecomment-1534484042

Should I open a bug into https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe-5.19 to get Ubuntu kernel maintainers help me collect further symptoms ?

Note: I don't directly have access to the KVM hypervisor hosts

Comment: Reported bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2019108